# How to vertically align tabulator separated values in Notepad++

Tags: python, csv, notepad++

I have a txt file with 406'000 lines (100MB size) and would like to view it with Notepad++ instead of Excel, because it's much faster.

How can I separate columns with a tabulator delimiter?

I'm refering to this post:
[How to vertically align comma separated values in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165105/how-to-vertically-align-comma-separated-values-in-notepad)

I really appreciate the answer from zerokelvin:

> You can use this python plugin script which utilizes the csv library
> which takes care of quoted csv and many other variants.
>
> Setup:
>
> ---
>
> 1. Use the plugin manager in Notepad++ to install the "Python script" plugin.
> 2. Plugins->Python Script->New Script (name it something like CSVtoTable.py)
> 3. Paste the following python script into the new file and save:
>
> CSVtoTable.py
>
> ```py
> import csv
>
> inputlines = editor.getText().split('\n')
> # Get rid of empty lines
> inputlines = [line.strip() for line in inputlines if line.strip()]
> reader = csv.reader(inputlines, delimiter=',')
> csvlist = [line for line in reader]
> # transpose to calculate the column widths and create a format string which left aligns each row
> t_csvlist = zip(*csvlist)
> col_widths = [max([len(x) for x in t_csvlist[y]]) for y in range(len(t_csvlist))]
> # To right align - change < to >
> fmt_str = ' '.join(['{{:<{0}}}'.format(x) for x in col_widths]) + '\r\n'
>
> text = []
> for line in csvlist: 
>     text.append(fmt_str.format(*line))
>
> # open a new document and put the results in there.    
> notepad.new()
> editor.addText(''.join(text))
> ```
>
> 4. Open your CSV file in notepad++
> 5. Click on Plugins->Python Script->Scripts->(The name you used in step 2)
> 6. A new tab with the formatted data should open.
>
> Update (right aligned numbers & left aligned strings):
> ------- Use the following python script if you want to right align number fields from the CSV - it looks at the second line of the csv to
> determine the types of the fields.
>
> ```py
> import csv
> import re
>
> num_re = re.compile('[-\+]?\d+(\.\d+)?')
>
> inputlines = editor.getText().split('\n')
> # Get rid of empty lines
> inputlines = [line.strip() for line in inputlines if line.strip()]
> reader = csv.reader(inputlines, delimiter=',')
> csvlist = [line for line in reader]
>
> # Transpose to calculate the column widths and create a format string which left aligns each row
> t_csvlist = zip(*csvlist)
> col_widths = [max([len(x) for x in t_csvlist[y]]) for y in range(len(t_csvlist))]
>
> # Numbers get right aligned
> type_eval_line = csvlist[1 if len(csvlist)>1 else 0]
> alignment = ['>' if num_re.match(item) else '<' for item in type_eval_line]
>
> # Compute the format string
> fmt_str = ' '.join(['{{:{0}{1}}}'.format(a,x) for x,a in zip(col_widths,alignment)]) + '\r\n'
>
> text = []
> for line in csvlist: 
>     text.append(fmt_str.format(*line))
>
> # open a new document and put the results in there.    
> notepad.new()
> editor.addText(''.join(text))
> ```

How can this Python script be modified if the delimiter is not a comma but a tabulator?

Addendum (Data File):

```py
Rec#    Cyc#    Step    TestTime    StepTime    Amp-hr  Watt-hr Amps    Volts   State   ES  DPt Time    ACImp/Ohms  DCIR/Ohms   Aux #1   Units  VAR1    VAR2    VAR3    VAR4    VAR5    VAR6    VAR7    VAR8    VAR9    VAR10   VAR11   VAR12   VAR13   VAR14   VAR15   
1   0   1     0d 00:00:0.140000000596046      0d 00:00:0.140000000596046    0.00001 0.00005 0.00000 3.41497 R   0   08/14/2017 16:42:26 0.00000 0.00000 12.71681            0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 
2   0   1     0d 00:00:0.140000000596046      0d 00:00:0.140000000596046    0.00001 0.00005 0.00000 3.41497 R   1   08/14/2017 16:42:26 0.00000 0.00000 12.71681            0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

A tabulator, as a special character, can be written literally using an "escape sequence": `\t`

So, you should probably just change this part: `delimiter=','` to this `delimiter='\t'` in your python code.

Comment: It works, but unfortunately only the first two columns are displayed.

Comment: Could you please copy paste one or two lines of example data from your csv?

Comment: also, do you use the first script or the second?

Comment: I've pasted the two lines from the csv above. I use the first script, but the second script doesn't work neither.

Comment: thank you for that. Also, sorry for not mentioning it but special spaces are not preserved in Stack Overflow text area. Are you certain that, on your actual data, there are _only_ tabs as separator? (and only one in between each field)? You can check this with an hexeditor for instance.

Comment: thank you. I've verified with https://hexed.it (nice online hexeditor) that there are only tabs (hex code 09) as separator, and only one in between each field.