# Consistent-length output from regex

Tags: notepad++

I am working with a file that contains data like this on each line:

```
'string1', 'string2',    'string3', 'string4', '8/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b', 'another string 4 value', '12/31/23', 'string5'
```

I need to make the file readable as formatted text, meaning columns begin and end at specific distances from the beginning of the line.  Most of the string columns I was able to adjust manually easily by using block editing.  `string4` values vary too wildly to easily do it manually.  I need to pad something to make columns align.

I am able to find the value I want to adjust using a regular expression

```
('[^']+', '\d+/)
```

So if I pad the first `string4` value with 15 spaces on the left                `$1`...

```
'string1', 'string2',    'string3',                'string4', '8/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b', 'another string 4 value', '12/31/23', 'string5'
```

...that's fine.  But if I do a find/replace ALL that will also pad the second `string4` value with 15 spaces.

Is there a way to craft a regular expression for the replacement to make it make the overall width (comma to comma) of the `string4` column the same for every row?

Desired result at this step of my process would look something like:

```
'string1', 'string2',    'string3',                                              'string4', '8/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b',                               'another string 4 value', '12/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b', 'A quick, red fox jumped over - the "lazy" brown dog.', '10/31/23', 'string5'  
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b',                                                    'b', '7/31/23', 'string5'
```

Note:  I don't see any apostrophes in my `string4` data -- only as the string identifier.  Let's not consider that edge case for now.

Comment: Does the readable format needs to be in csv as well? Or can you display it as text table? If you just want a tabular format you can try https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables you can paste your csv and generate a more readable table

Comment: Isn't it possible to move the 4th column at the end? That would be the easiest solution...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align comma separated values in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165105/how-to-vertically-align-comma-separated-values-in-notepad)

Comment: @AdrianHHH Wow!  Awesome!  I'll definitely look at that plugin to see what else it provides.  But having had plugins crash or become incompatible over time, I think the regex solution will live longer.

Comment: Just to head off other comments about CSV:  This isn't actually CSV.  It's the relevant part of the file -- and even each line -- I'm working with.  There is other complexity that is not germane to this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions is it not possible to do calculations using the length of a match.

What you can do however is to match an exact number of characters using the `(pattern){number}` syntax, for example `([abc]){5}` matches sequences of length five containing the letters a, b or c in any combination.

Therefore you can use a two-step approach. First, pad the column with enough spaces to cover the widest value. Then you can match the sequence  `*[random characters]{n}column_separator` with `n` equal to the length of the widest value. The idea is that the random characters also include the space character, so some of the spaces will be matched by  `*` and the rest of the spaces together with the real column value, *up to a total width of n*, will be matched by `[random characters]{n}`.

Then you can replace by the match with the n characters, discarding the (variable) number of spaces in front.

To prevent the n random characters to include the whole column, the separator, and the next column, it is needed to match the remaining columns until the end of the line as well. This can be prevented if you are certain that the separator character does not occur inside of the column, then you can just match on `[^separator]{n}`. Note that you *cannot* match the opening `'` separately because this needs to be somewhere in the middle of `[]{n}` for this approach to work.

I don't have Notepad++ available but I tested the following code using gedit. The replace syntax is different as gedit uses `\n` instead of `$n` but the matching is most likely the same. I didn't really understand how your first snippet is supposed to match the fourth column so I wrote a matching expression using the first matching group for the first three columns combined and the third matching group for the fourth column (the second matching group is inside of the first and repeated three times).

Step 1: padding
Search: `(( *'[^']+',){3})( *'[^']+')`
Replace: `\1                    \3` (20 spaces padded)

Result:

```
'string1', 'string2',    'string3',                     'string4', '8/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b',                     'another string 4 value', '12/31/23', 'string5'
```

Step two: trimming down to 25 characters. Match and replace also the last two columns.
Search: `(( *'[^']+',){3}) *(.{25}',)(( *'[^']+',){1}( *'[^']+'))`
Replace: `\1\3\4`
Result:

```
'string1', 'string2',    'string3',                 'string4', '8/31/23', 'string5'
'string1', 'string2',  'string3 b',  'another string 4 value', '12/31/23', 'string5'
```

Note that for this approach it is needed to know the length of the widest column. If you don't know that then you can use a variation of the same technique. Instead of matching an exact number of characters, you can match *up to* a number using the syntax `{0,n}` or equivalently `{,n}`. Use this by first matching, for example, `'[^']{0,12}'` on the column. If the total number of matches is lower than the number of lines in the file then there are longer values. Then match twice as many characters, `'[^']{0,24}'`. If this still doesn't match everything then go to 48, etc, otherwise go down to the value in the middle, i.e., `'[^']{0,18}'`. Then go up to 21 or down to 15, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured it would be two steps.